# Express js:multiple route files into single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

In my express.js application i am organizing my routes in following way

**routes/comment.js(handle all the comment routes)**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var comment = require('../controller/comment');
router.route('/new').get(comment.create);
module.exports = router;
```

**routes/post.js(handle all the post routes)**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var post = require('../controller/post');
router.route('/new').get(post.create);
module.exports = router;
```

And i am including in **app.js** file  like this way

```
//need to include these declarations into another file and include that file here
  //eg: require('config/main-routes');

    /*
     routes like comment/new
    */
    var comment  = require('./routes/comment');
    app.use('/comment',comment);
    /*
     routes like post/new
    */
    var post  = require('./routes/post');
    app.use('/post',post)
```

This works fine however i want to include this into another file lets say `config/route-main.js` and link this to `app.js` file

How can i do that??

Comment: I don't understand.
Do you want to combine these 2 files into single file?

Comment: nop,want to include route declarations in `app.js` file to an another file

Comment: @RishabhMishra question edited with relevant comments in app.js file i hope this will clarify your doubts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in `app.js` include

```
var routes  = require('./config/route-main');
app.use('/',routes);
```

and in route-config.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var comment  = require('./routes/comment');
var post  = require('./routes/post');

router.use('/comment',comment);
router.use('/post',post)


module.exports = router
```

check this link:

https://katieleonard.ca/blog/2016/2016-04-12-nested-routes-with-expressjs/

Answer (score 2):

Your `app.js` file:

```
const Express = require('express');
const app = Express();

const Routes = require('./routes');
app.use('', Routes);
```

Your `routes.js` file:

```
const Express = require('express');
const Router = Express.Router();

const UsersController = require('./controllers/usersController');

Router.post('/users', UsersController.CreateUser);

module.exports = Router;
```

Your `usersController.js` file:

```
const CreateUser = (req, res, next) => {
  // DO STUFF HERE
}

module.exports = {
  CreateUser
}
```